# How can I prove $S[X] =\{f(a_1,...,a_n):n∈N, f∈S[x_1,...,x_n], a_1,...,a_n ∈ X\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a problem with this exercise. It says:

> Let $A$ ring, $S⊆A$ ring and $X$ a set $X⊆A$. Let $S[X]$ the least ring which contains $X∪S$. Prove
>   $S[X] =\{f(a_1,...,a_n):n∈N, f∈S[x_1,...,x_n], a_1,...,a_n ∈ X\}.   \tag 1$

I´ve tried to prove it like in Set theory, but I can´t!

Suggestions will be very appreciated

Comment: I edited  your question to $\LaTeX$ify it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is clear that $T:=\{f(a_1,...,a_n):n\in\mathbb{N},f\in S[x_1,...,x_n],a_1,...,a_n\in X\}$ is a subring of $A$, and that it contains $X$ and $S$. So to prove that it is the smallest subring containing $S\cup X$, it remains only to prove that any other subring of $A$ containing $X$ and $S$ contains $T$.

So, suppose that $R$ is a subring of $A$ with $S\cup X \subseteq R$. Then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f\in S[x_1,...,x_n]$, $a_1,...,a_n\in X$, clearly $a_1,...,a_n\in R$ and $f\in R[x_1,...,x_n]$, and hence $f(a_1,...,a_n)\in R$. Therefore every element of $T$ belongs to $R$.